# What is the algorithm for selecting the best scene of a video?

Tags: algorithm, youtube, data-mining, video-processing

When we upload a video to Youtube or other video sharing sites, the site automatically selects the best or the most representative scene from the video to show as the icon of the video. How is that done?
I want to know which data mining or other algorithms to study to extract the most relevant scene from a video. Any pointers to literature or implementations would be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that the "algorithm" is roughly (in pseudo-code):

```
Random(0, clip.Length)
```

Comment: But, slightly more serious... I think somewhere in the first 5-10 seconds. Just as scientific, of course.

Comment: @Sam I thought about it, but figured that it probably wasn't worth it - if enough of the video is black to make it reasonably likely that we would get an all black frame, then an all black frame would actually be a representative frame anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you are right but to me the scene selection never looks to be random.

Comment: It's prolly 20% into the clip.

Answer (score 5):

My guess:

1. `i` = 1
2. Compare frame `i` with frame `i-1` (using e.g. sum of squared difference in pixel colour intensities)
3. Is the difference > preset_threshold?

   1. If yes: A sequence of below-threshold frames has just ended.  Is this the longest sequence yet?

      1. If yes: `best` = start of this sequence.
4. `i++`
5. If `i < length_of_clip`: Goto 2.
6. Choose frame `best`.

The idea is: Find the longest "scene" (series of frames whose transitions are below some arbitrary threshold), and show the first frame in that series.

Comment: In single-sequence videos, the selected is scene is rarely the first scene. So even after selecting the longest sequence, the problem of finding the most relevant scene from that sequence still persists.

Comment: @nabeelmukhtar: It might be that an image from some fixed proportion (e.g. 10%) into the longest scene is taken.  (I assume by "scene" you mean "frame".)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to extract some frames of a video and display them randomly. By tracking the user's click through rate, Youtube already know how to rank those frames.